# Возможно ли показывать карты в изометрической проекции (псевдо-3D), скрывать 3D модели зданий?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Возможно ли включать режим показа карт в изометрической проекции -- как на yandex.maps при Ctrl-Drag или "джойстик" 2D/3D. Предполагал, что это могло бы находиться где-нибудь в опциях конструктора карт (https://yandex.com/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map.html), но не вижу там ничего похоже.

Аналогично -- возможно ли выключать режим показа 3D зданий при больших зумах (чтобы здания показывались плоскими прямоугольниками, без учёта "высоты")?

Где искать соответствующие настройки? Они вообще есть?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из службы поддержки Яндекса, для истории и для тех, кто, возможно, будет интересоваться этим вопросом в будущем:

> Здравствуйте!
>
> 1. В настоящее время JavaScript API ещё не работает с трёхмерной векторной картой, такой, которая используется в нашем веб-сервисе. Потому включить это никак нельзя.
> 2. В API Яндекс.Карт подложка отрисована в единственно возможном на данный момент варианте. Тайлы для всех масштабов подгружаются в виде растровых изображений и возможности их изменить кодом (2D/3D) также не существует.
>
> Мы собираем и изучаем все пожелания, поступающие от пользователей, и реализуем наиболее полезные и популярные из них.
>
> Я внес ваше предложение в список пользовательских фичреквестов. Мы непременно подробно рассмотрим его при обновлении сервиса в будущем. Следите за нашими обновлениями в клубе разработчиков.

Answer (score 0):

Текущая версия [JS API](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/quick-start/index-docpage/) не работает с векторными картами, используемыми на [Яндекс.Картах](https://maps.yandex.ru/), и методов включения такого режима нет. Но весьма разумно верить, что это будет реализовано в будущих версиях API с целью унификации.

Также нет никакой возможности отключить "псевдо-3D", поскольку в API доступны только предварительно отрисованные тайлы подложки - "схема" и "спутник".